# PCA with soil cover of plant species

Tags: pca, ecology

1. 8 plots (quadrants 3 x 3 meters), 4 invaded with an alien plant, 4 without the alien plant.
2. I have measured the soil cover (as %) of the species found in these 8 plots.
3. If I make a PCA with log (n+1) transformed values, the resulting PCA has low eigenvalues of the first two PC (corresponding to 34% and 28% of variance, respectively). Also loadings are mostly low (mostly < 0.30).
4. There are also many variables corresponding to species that are poorly represented in the plots (they are present in one or few plots with very low soil cover). The then scatter plot results a mess with many very short vectors.
5. I have read that this state of things could be due to multicollinearity and that it could be necessarity to exclude some of the variables.
6. Could it be that invaded and non-invaded plots are similar and then the overall variance is low?

So, how to deal with such data?

NB: I  am not using R

Comment: Its OK not to use R, but what DO you use?

Comment: Why are you doing a PCA at all?

Comment: What is the ecological question that you're trying to answer? For a similar example from an EDA perspective, see [Jegede *et at* 2023](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0282068).

Comment: 1) I am using PAST and PSPP

Comment: 2) I am somehow more familiar with PCA. But suggestions for other kinds of analysis are welcome.

Comment: 3) Thanks for the paper (Jegede et at 2023). I have not the possibility to measure ecological variables such as chemical characteristics but only species abundances expressed as soil cover. Unfortunately (or fortunately) this species at present occurs only in one meadow. It's just a first finding of... so, for the moment, I am interested to know if this small case could suggest something about the species that coexist with the alien and other that, apparently, tend to avoid this species.

Comment: @dandelion Note that you can put an `@` symbol before someone's username when responding to them. It will notify them. Otherwise they may not remember to look back here.